# Executar comandos do PROMPT / CMD no Java

Tags: java, cmd, runtime, prompt

Bom pessoal, gostaria de saber como executar no Java esse comando:

```
attrib -R -A -S -H /S /D I:\*.*
```

Este programinha é para limpar vírus de pendrive. Já consultei alguns materiais aqui no fórum, mas não consegui aplicar.

Basicamente o usuário vai digitar a letra do seu pendrive e clicar em botão de executar, onde fará os comandos abaixo.

```
String cmd, caminho,comando_01,comando_02;
        String[] executar;
        //************************************************
        cmd = "cmd /c"; // chamada para o cmd
        caminho = txtCaminhoTelaDois.getText() + ":"; //pegando caminho digitado
        comando_01 = "attrib -R -A -S -H /S /D" + caminho + "\\*.*";
        comando_02 = "del *.lnk";

        executar = new String[2];
        executar[0] = cmd + " " + caminho;
        executar[1] = cmd + " " + comando_02;

        //************************************************
        Runtime comando = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process proc = comando.exec(executar);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Concluído");
        }

        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TelaDois.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deu ruim...");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você não está alterando a letra da unidade que está tentando acessar.
Primeiro coloque este método abaixo no seu programa para melhor reutilização:

```
public String executar(String... comandos) {
  StringBuilder saida = new StringBuilder();
  BufferedReader leitor;
  ProcessBuilder processos;
  Process processo;

  try {
    processos = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", String.join(" && ", comandos));
    processo = processos.start();
    processo.waitFor();
    leitor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processo.getInputStream()));

    String linha = "";

    while ((linha = leitor.readLine()) != null) {
      saida.append(linha).append("\n");
    }
  } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
    return ex.getMessage();
  }

  return saida.toString();
}
```

Depois na chamada utilize:

```
this.executar("D:", comando_01, comando_02);
```

Ou altere seu executar para:

```
executar = new String[3];
executar[0] = "D:";
executar[1] = comando_01;
executar[2] = comando_02;
this.executar(executar);
```

Note que não é necessário passar o caminho do `cmd`. Também é importante notar que você deve pegar a letra do `drive` desejado pelo usuário.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que isso daqui está errado:

```
        comando_01 = "attrib -R -A -S -H /S /D" + caminho + "\\*.*";
```

Acho que deveria ser isso:

```
        comando_01 = "attrib -R -A -S -H /S /D " + caminho + "\\*.*";
```

Observe o espaço após o `/D`.

E depois tem isso:

```
        executar[0] = cmd + " " + caminho;
```

Deveria ser:

```
        executar[0] = cmd + " " + comando_01;
```